# How to exclude number in random number in Java

Tags: java, loops, random, while-loop

So I will get a random number between 1 to 9999, but I want to exclude 1111, 3333, 4444, 7777 and is that use while loop?

```
Random r = new Random();

int x = r.nextInt(9999);

while (x == 1111 || x==3333){
    x = r.nextInt(9999) + 1;
}
```

Comment: You don't declare x before the while... This code won't work. You'll need to check `random`

Comment: It is unclear what are you asking! Please edit your question to include exactly what do you want?

Comment: @kappa If the solution below solves your problem, you can accept the solution by clicking the hollow tick beside the solution. You get 2 rep points in return.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is fine. You may also use a do-while loop. So that it will generate a random number first, then check.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int x=0;
do{
    x = rnd.nextInt(9999)+1;
}while(x==1111 || x==3333 || x==4444 || x==7777);
```

Comment: @kappa `but while (x == 1111 || x == 3333 || x == 4444 || x == 7777) { x = r.nextInt(9999); } `The code will work. You can test it from 1-9 and exclude 1,3,4,7.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in this case the `while` means that it will continue to process a new random number until it is different from 1111 or 3333 on your code.

There is nothing wrong with your code, only minor things.

1 - Fix your while to attend your condition:

```
while (x == 1111 || x == 3333 || x == 4444 || x == 7777)
```

2 - The method `nextInt` process a random number from 0 (inclusive) to the given number exclusive as the Javadocs states (thanks to @user3437460):

> Returns a pseudorandom, uniformly distributed {@code int} value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive), drawn from this random number generator's sequence.

So:

```
Random r = new Random();
int x = r.nextInt(9999)+1;
while (x == 1111 || x == 3333 || x == 4444 || x == 7777) {
    x = r.nextInt(9999) + 1;
}
System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: r.nextInt(9999) will generate 0 - 9998. Are you sure your solution is correct?

Comment: but while (x == 1111 || x == 3333 || x == 4444 || x == 7777) {
    x = r.nextInt(9999);
} still have chance to get 1111

Comment: you can use a do { ... } while(....); which will remove the duplicate r.nextInt(9999) + 1

Comment: yes @Thierry ! You should add your suggestion as an answer! I would gladly upvote it, since it will be a better suggestion than my one :)

Comment: @JorgeCampos Your solution is still incorrect. r.nextInt(10000) will generate 0 - 9999 !

Comment: @user3437460 Yeah, realize that now! 0 != 1 thanks again.