# how to exclude prime number from random number math quiz?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, math

I tried this for my math quiz and it works wonders, but I did not get the fractional part:

```
public void gameContinue() {
  int num1 = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
  java.util.List<Integer> firstNumDivisors = getDivisors(num1);

  int divisorsRandIndex = (int) (Math.random() * firstNumDivisors.size());
  int num2 = firstNumDivisors.get(divisorsRandIndex);

  question.setText(num1 + " ÷ " + num2);
  
  // Create your question from first and second numbers here
}

private static java.util.List<Integer> getDivisors (int number) {
  java.util.List<Integer> divisors = new java.util.ArrayList<>();

  for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
    if (number % i == 0)
      divisors.add(i);
  return divisors;
}
```

But after some testing, I do not want to include prime numbers (more than 10 like 11, 13, 17, 19 and so on) and I also do not want the answer to be more than 10 (11, 12, 13 and so on)

Should I make a string for prime numbers and make the program exclude those? Also, how can I make the answer to be no more than 10?

Thank you

Comment: Another way would be to check whether a number is prime [by calculating it on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44367443/133203).

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca so after i add that i need to write the program to exclude those? sorry if i'm so slow to catch since i still learning about android studio

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how your code works or what it's supposed to do but I'm *guessing* it should go in `getDivisors` where you check whether you want to add `i` to `divisors`, so something like `if (number % i == 0 && !isPrime(i))`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i will try it first  
also i get the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/66447822/19688576
thanks

Comment: Note that your question was already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73232555

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Some points of your question required some interpretation - hopefully I was correct; otherwise, just add a comment and I'll try to adapt.)

### Require answer always <= 10

To ensure the selected divisor does not result in an "answer" more than 10, then simply restrict the divisors added to the divisor list.

Modify the one line in `getDivisors` as such:

```
// i is an integral divisor and the resulting quotient is <= 10
if (number % i == 0 && number / i <= 10)
```

Then when the code randomly selects a divisor from the list, the "answer" to the question:

> num1 ÷ num2

will always be <= 10, where num1 is a number from 1 to 100 (inclusive) and num2 is the randomly selected integral divisor.

### Exclude some dividends (`num1`)

In order to exclude certain numbers from a range (for your `num1`) you could do it as a loop as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33945385/17856705).

Or you could create a list of the acceptable numbers and then use `Random` to provide an index into your acceptable list [(credit reference answer for list creation)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56121713/17856705):

```
// an array of acceptable numbers as dividend
int[] acceptableNums = IntStream.range(1, 101).filter(a -> !java.util.List.of(11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97).contains(a)).toArray();

// here i chose to use "r" which is java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random() because my test involved a loop and I want to get uniform distribution over the loop.
int num1 = acceptableNums[r.nextInt(acceptableNums.length)];
```

So the complete test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();

    int[] acceptableNums = IntStream.range(1, 101).filter(a -> !java.util.List.of(11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97).contains(a)).toArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        int num1 = acceptableNums[r.nextInt(acceptableNums.length)];
        java.util.List<Integer> firstNumDivisors = getDivisors(num1);

        int divisorsRandIndex = (int) (Math.random() * firstNumDivisors.size());
        int num2 = firstNumDivisors.get(divisorsRandIndex);


        System.out.println("What is " + num1 + " ÷ " + num2+ " (Answer: "+num1/num2+")");
        // Create your question from first and second numbers here
        
    }
}

    private static java.util.List<Integer> getDivisors ( int number){
        java.util.List<Integer> divisors = new java.util.ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
            if (number % i == 0 && number / i <= 10)
                divisors.add(i);

        return divisors;
    }
```

And the output:

```
What is 78 ÷ 39 (Answer: 2)
What is 1 ÷ 1 (Answer: 1)
What is 32 ÷ 8 (Answer: 4)
What is 68 ÷ 17 (Answer: 4)
What is 26 ÷ 13 (Answer: 2)
What is 94 ÷ 47 (Answer: 2)
What is 46 ÷ 23 (Answer: 2)
What is 68 ÷ 68 (Answer: 1)
What is 10 ÷ 2 (Answer: 5)
What is 70 ÷ 10 (Answer: 7)
What is 38 ÷ 38 (Answer: 1)
What is 75 ÷ 75 (Answer: 1)
What is 1 ÷ 1 (Answer: 1)
What is 90 ÷ 30 (Answer: 3)
What is 62 ÷ 62 (Answer: 1)
What is 95 ÷ 95 (Answer: 1)
What is 60 ÷ 6 (Answer: 10)
What is 27 ÷ 3 (Answer: 9)
What is 5 ÷ 1 (Answer: 5)
What is 28 ÷ 14 (Answer: 2)
What is 1 ÷ 1 (Answer: 1)
What is 70 ÷ 14 (Answer: 5)
What is 21 ÷ 21 (Answer: 1)
What is 40 ÷ 40 (Answer: 1)
What is 51 ÷ 17 (Answer: 3)
What is 24 ÷ 12 (Answer: 2)
What is 5 ÷ 1 (Answer: 5)
What is 58 ÷ 58 (Answer: 1)
What is 91 ÷ 91 (Answer: 1)
What is 91 ÷ 13 (Answer: 7)
What is 94 ÷ 94 (Answer: 1)
What is 28 ÷ 14 (Answer: 2)
What is 46 ÷ 23 (Answer: 2)
What is 95 ÷ 95 (Answer: 1)
What is 58 ÷ 58 (Answer: 1)
What is 2 ÷ 2 (Answer: 1)
What is 55 ÷ 55 (Answer: 1)
What is 20 ÷ 5 (Answer: 4)
What is 92 ÷ 23 (Answer: 4)
What is 21 ÷ 21 (Answer: 1)
What is 10 ÷ 5 (Answer: 2)
What is 1 ÷ 1 (Answer: 1)
What is 69 ÷ 69 (Answer: 1)
What is 84 ÷ 21 (Answer: 4)
What is 96 ÷ 24 (Answer: 4)
What is 90 ÷ 45 (Answer: 2)
What is 88 ÷ 44 (Answer: 2)
What is 88 ÷ 22 (Answer: 4)
What is 72 ÷ 36 (Answer: 2)
What is 40 ÷ 5 (Answer: 8)
What is 8 ÷ 4 (Answer: 2)
What is 10 ÷ 2 (Answer: 5)
What is 24 ÷ 3 (Answer: 8)
What is 66 ÷ 66 (Answer: 1)
What is 90 ÷ 30 (Answer: 3)
What is 66 ÷ 66 (Answer: 1)
What is 58 ÷ 58 (Answer: 1)
What is 91 ÷ 91 (Answer: 1)
What is 58 ÷ 58 (Answer: 1)
What is 28 ÷ 7 (Answer: 4)
What is 96 ÷ 16 (Answer: 6)
What is 90 ÷ 30 (Answer: 3)
What is 91 ÷ 91 (Answer: 1)
What is 12 ÷ 4 (Answer: 3)
What is 4 ÷ 4 (Answer: 1)
What is 84 ÷ 84 (Answer: 1)
What is 8 ÷ 1 (Answer: 8)
What is 49 ÷ 7 (Answer: 7)
What is 14 ÷ 7 (Answer: 2)
What is 16 ÷ 8 (Answer: 2)
What is 51 ÷ 17 (Answer: 3)
```

### Inverse Approach

Given the comment below clarifying the desired result, the inverse approach to the equation is simpler and has the benefit of naturally eliminating the primes > 10.  (A number 1..10 multiplied by a number 1..10 cannot result in a prime > 10.)

```
    java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        int num2 = r.nextInt(10) + 1;
        int answer = r.nextInt(10) + 1;

        int num1 = num2 * answer;
        
        System.out.println("What is " + num1 + " ÷ " + num2+ " (Answer: "+answer+")");
        // Create your question from first and second numbers here
        
    }
```

And result from inverse approach:

```
What is 21 ÷ 7 (Answer: 3)
What is 4 ÷ 1 (Answer: 4)
What is 100 ÷ 10 (Answer: 10)
What is 40 ÷ 4 (Answer: 10)
What is 64 ÷ 8 (Answer: 8)
What is 16 ÷ 8 (Answer: 2)
What is 14 ÷ 2 (Answer: 7)
What is 63 ÷ 7 (Answer: 9)
What is 56 ÷ 7 (Answer: 8)
What is 4 ÷ 2 (Answer: 2)
What is 10 ÷ 2 (Answer: 5)
What is 18 ÷ 6 (Answer: 3)
What is 5 ÷ 5 (Answer: 1)
What is 42 ÷ 7 (Answer: 6)
What is 5 ÷ 1 (Answer: 5)
What is 54 ÷ 6 (Answer: 9)
What is 14 ÷ 2 (Answer: 7)
What is 14 ÷ 2 (Answer: 7)
What is 50 ÷ 5 (Answer: 10)
What is 36 ÷ 6 (Answer: 6)
What is 12 ÷ 6 (Answer: 2)
What is 56 ÷ 8 (Answer: 7)
What is 24 ÷ 8 (Answer: 3)
What is 12 ÷ 4 (Answer: 3)
What is 20 ÷ 5 (Answer: 4)
What is 100 ÷ 10 (Answer: 10)
What is 36 ÷ 4 (Answer: 9)
What is 18 ÷ 9 (Answer: 2)
What is 48 ÷ 6 (Answer: 8)
What is 40 ÷ 4 (Answer: 10)
What is 42 ÷ 6 (Answer: 7)
What is 8 ÷ 2 (Answer: 4)
What is 18 ÷ 2 (Answer: 9)
What is 18 ÷ 3 (Answer: 6)
What is 70 ÷ 10 (Answer: 7)
What is 8 ÷ 1 (Answer: 8)
What is 12 ÷ 3 (Answer: 4)
What is 24 ÷ 6 (Answer: 4)
What is 8 ÷ 4 (Answer: 2)
What is 6 ÷ 3 (Answer: 2)
What is 20 ÷ 10 (Answer: 2)
What is 30 ÷ 6 (Answer: 5)
What is 70 ÷ 10 (Answer: 7)
What is 42 ÷ 6 (Answer: 7)
What is 6 ÷ 2 (Answer: 3)
What is 15 ÷ 3 (Answer: 5)
What is 12 ÷ 3 (Answer: 4)
What is 10 ÷ 2 (Answer: 5)
What is 70 ÷ 7 (Answer: 10)
What is 6 ÷ 1 (Answer: 6)
What is 80 ÷ 8 (Answer: 10)
What is 7 ÷ 1 (Answer: 7)
What is 45 ÷ 5 (Answer: 9)
What is 21 ÷ 7 (Answer: 3)
What is 48 ÷ 6 (Answer: 8)
What is 12 ÷ 3 (Answer: 4)
What is 21 ÷ 3 (Answer: 7)
What is 48 ÷ 8 (Answer: 6)
What is 80 ÷ 8 (Answer: 10)
What is 50 ÷ 5 (Answer: 10)
What is 18 ÷ 3 (Answer: 6)
What is 24 ÷ 8 (Answer: 3)
What is 30 ÷ 5 (Answer: 6)
What is 54 ÷ 9 (Answer: 6)
What is 8 ÷ 8 (Answer: 1)
What is 8 ÷ 8 (Answer: 1)
What is 40 ÷ 8 (Answer: 5)
What is 6 ÷ 1 (Answer: 6)
What is 60 ÷ 10 (Answer: 6)
What is 60 ÷ 6 (Answer: 10)
What is 45 ÷ 9 (Answer: 5)
What is 48 ÷ 6 (Answer: 8)
What is 50 ÷ 5 (Answer: 10)
What is 24 ÷ 3 (Answer: 8)
What is 6 ÷ 3 (Answer: 2)
What is 5 ÷ 1 (Answer: 5)
What is 4 ÷ 1 (Answer: 4)
What is 20 ÷ 4 (Answer: 5)
What is 9 ÷ 3 (Answer: 3)
What is 45 ÷ 5 (Answer: 9)
What is 3 ÷ 1 (Answer: 3)
What is 6 ÷ 2 (Answer: 3)
What is 54 ÷ 6 (Answer: 9)
What is 21 ÷ 3 (Answer: 7)
What is 50 ÷ 10 (Answer: 5)
What is 20 ÷ 5 (Answer: 4)
What is 6 ÷ 3 (Answer: 2)
What is 10 ÷ 10 (Answer: 1)
What is 60 ÷ 6 (Answer: 10)
What is 10 ÷ 10 (Answer: 1)
What is 72 ÷ 9 (Answer: 8)
What is 15 ÷ 5 (Answer: 3)
What is 16 ÷ 8 (Answer: 2)
What is 70 ÷ 10 (Answer: 7)
What is 24 ÷ 4 (Answer: 6)
What is 16 ÷ 8 (Answer: 2)
What is 80 ÷ 10 (Answer: 8)
What is 40 ÷ 10 (Answer: 4)
What is 12 ÷ 6 (Answer: 2)
What is 16 ÷ 2 (Answer: 8)
```

Comment: hello, thanks for answering, what i mean require answer <=10 also means num 2 always <=10 since i want this program to be use for children, for example 48 ÷ 6 = 8 or 60 ÷10 = 6 so i want to add condtion where num 2 always <=10 and the answer also <=10. is that possible?

Comment: If that is the case it is easier for the code to do the "inverse approach" as in the following: pick a number 1..10 (answer) and pick a number 1..10 (dividend) and `num1` = answer * dividend.  Then form the question - essentially work in reverse.  This also naturally eliminates the undesirable primes.  Added this approach...